# Shortcut Ctrl+Down in Action

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qt-quick, qtquickcontrols

I would like to have an `Action` which triggers on the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd>.

What I was able to do is have the shortcut for <kbd>↓</kbd>:

```
Action {
    shortcut: StandardKey.MoveToNextLine
    enabled: true
    onTriggered: console.log('Down pressed')
}
```

But how can I define the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-action.html#shortcut-prop) of `shortcut` you read that:

> Shortcut bound to the action. The keysequence can be a **string** or a **standard key**.

From the `QKeySequence` `toString()` method [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qkeysequence.html#toString) you also read that:

> Return a string representation of the key sequence, based on format.
>
> For example, the value Qt::CTRL+Qt::Key_O results in "**Ctrl+O**". If the key sequence has multiple key codes, each is separated by commas in the string returned, such as "Alt+X, Ctrl+Y, Z". The strings, "Ctrl", "Shift", etc. are translated using QObject::tr() in the "QShortcut" context.

Hence, use the key name combination instead of `StandardKey` like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3

ApplicationWindow {
    id: rectangle
    width: 200
    height: 200
    visible: true

    Action {
        shortcut: "Ctrl+Down"
        enabled: true
        onTriggered: console.log('Down pressed [ctrl hold]')
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use something similar:

```
Keys.onPressed: {
    if ((event.key == Qt.Key_Down) && (event.modifiers & Qt.ControlModifier))
        doSomething();
}
```